# How to store/retrieve last place an element was moved?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

Currently I am using this code:

```
var mousePosition;
var offset = [0,0];
var div;

var isDown = false;

div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "0px";  
div.style.top = "0px";
div.style.width = "237px";
div.style.height = "50px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.padding = "15px 0px 0px 0px";
div.style.color = "blue";
div.id = "clock";

document.body.appendChild(div);


div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
isDown = true;
offset = [
    div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
    div.offsetTop - e.clientY
];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
isDown = false;
}, true);


document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (isDown) {
    mousePosition = {

        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY

    };
    div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
    div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
```

The code allows me to move a div using my mouse. I'm not very experienced with JavaScript.

But I was hoping there is an easy method to cache the end location of the Div. So that when I close and open the HTML file, the Div will start in its last cached location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to cache the location information into your browser.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('divPosition', JSON.stringify({
  left: div.style.left, 
  top: div.style.top
}));

console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('divPosition')));
```

One caveat is that localStorage doesn't reliably accept anything but string values so adding more robust information requires stringifying and parsing the data.

Comment: How exactly would I go about implementing this in the above code?
Do I need to implement some type of function loop?
That triggers when the Div moves or does this code auto update?